# get information about pytables metadata

Tags: python, pytables

Is there any way to iterate over the fields of a table metaclass object? (NOT the table itself, I need to do some preliminary analysis before a table is even instantiated)

I'm not really familiar with metaclasses in Python, so this is mystery stuff to me.

```
class Particle(IsDescription):
    name        = StringCol(16, pos=1)   # 16-character String
    lati        = IntCol(pos=2)        # integer
    longi       = IntCol(pos=3)        # integer
    pressure    = Float32Col(pos=4)    # float  (single-precision)
    temperature = FloatCol(pos=5)      # double (double-precision)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns attribute on the class is a dictionary of column named keys to the data type values.  You should then be able to iterate over this dictionary like you would any Python dictionary (keys(), values(), items(), etc).

```
In [7]: Particle.columns
Out[7]: 
{'lati': Int32Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=2),
 'longi': Int32Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=3),
 'name': StringCol(itemsize=16, shape=(), dflt='', pos=1),
 'pressure': Float32Col(shape=(), dflt=0.0, pos=4),
 'temperature': Float64Col(shape=(), dflt=0.0, pos=5)}
```